# Fetch rows from a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes df1 and df2. I would like to check if id2 value exists in df2. If exists, fetch the rows in df1 with identical id1 values. I tried left join but it gives only the first row.

```
pd.merge(df1, df2.rename(columns={'id1':'id2'}), on='id2', how='left')
```

```
df1

id1     id2    id3
C45     AB     ZU
C45     ZO     RE
C67     RT     FG
C78     TZ     GH
```

```
df2

id1
AB
GH
ZU
```

Expected output is:

```
id1     id2    id3
C45     AB     ZU
C45     ZO     RE
```

Comment: What code did you use to get that frame

Comment: pd.merge(df1, df2.rename(columns={'id1':'id2'}), on='id2',  how='left')

Comment: please include it in your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it in 2 separate steps.

First, find all the items in df1.id1 which match df2.id1 and save them to `lookup`.

Then, find all the rows which are in `lookup` within df1.id1 and save them to `final`.

First,

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
  
# initialize list of lists
data = [['C45', 'AB','ZU'], ['C45', 'ZO','RE'], ['C67', 'RT','FG'],['C78','TZ','GH']]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id1', 'id2', 'id3'])

# initialize list of lists
data = [['AB'], ['GH'], ['ZU']]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id1'])

lookup = df1[df1.id2.isin(df2.id1)].id1 # contains a series of the ids in df1.id2 that match df2.id1

final = df1[df1.id1.isin(lookup)]
```

final looks like this,

```
    id1     id2     id3
0   C45     AB      ZU
1   C45     ZO      RE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go, input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['C45','AB','ZU'],['C45','ZO','RE'],
   ['C67','RT','FG',],['C78','TZ','GH']], columns=['id1','id2','id3'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['AB','GH','ZU'], columns=['id1'])
```

the command:

```
df1[df1.id1.isin(df1.id1[df1.id2.isin(df2.id1)])]
```

output:

```
    id1 id2 id3
0   C45 AB  ZU
1   C45 ZO  RE
```

explanation, `df1.id2.isin(df2.id1)`:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
```

`df1.id1[df1.id2.isin(df2.id1)]`:

```
0    C45
```

`df1.id1.isin(df1.id1[df1.id2.isin(df2.id1)])`:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
```

Comment: The output is incorrect

Comment: Thanks @mozway, you are right, I didn't read the question correctly. I am updating the answer now.